# WARN: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000

Tags: java, hibernate, select

I have a problem with hibernate query.

UPDATE:
When I use this query it works like a charm:

```
public static List<Korisnik> UzmiSveKorisnike()
    {
        EntityManager em = Konekcija.getEmf().createEntityManager();

        TypedQuery<Korisnik> q = em.createQuery("select k from Korisnik k where k.isActive = 1", Korisnik.class); 
        List<Korisnik> resultList = q.getResultList();

        em.close();
        return resultList;
    }
```

But when I use one listed below, to select single result (like for login)...

I get this error: WARN: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000

I have tried variety of ways to implement this query, but without success. I will list them at the end of the post.

This is the code:

```
public static Korisnik ProvjeraKorisnickihPodataka(String kIme, String kLozinka)
    {
        EntityManager em = Konekcija.getEmf().createEntityManager();

    {
        TypedQuery<Korisnik> q = em.createQuery("select k from Korisnik k where k.isActive = 1 AND k.korisnickoIme=:ime AND k.lozinka =:lozinka", Korisnik.class); 
        q.setParameter("ime", kIme);
        q.setParameter("lozinka", kLozinka);
        Korisnik provjeren = q.getSingleResult();

        em.close();

        return provjeren;
```

Even if I replace :ime and :lozinka with actual data like "k.korisnickoIme='msbtest' and k.lozinka = 'msbtest'" I get the same error.

Your help is appreciated.

Thank you!

Complete stack:

```
Hibernate: select TOP(?) korisnik0_.KorisnikID as KorisnikID11_, korisnik0_.agencija_AgencijaID as agencija8_11_, korisnik0_.ime as ime11_, korisnik0_.isActive as isActive11_, korisnik0_.kontakt as kontakt11_, korisnik0_.korisnickoIme as korisnic5_11_, korisnik0_.lozinka as lozinka11_, korisnik0_.prezime as prezime11_, korisnik0_.rola_RolaID as rola9_11_ from Korisnik korisnik0_ where korisnik0_.isActive=1 and korisnik0_.korisnickoIme=? and korisnik0_.lozinka=?
Jul 05, 2013 11:45:22 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
Jul 05, 2013 11:45:22 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.KorisnikID as KorisnikID11_, korisnik0_.agencija_AgencijaID as agencija8_11_, k' at line 1
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.KorisnikID as KorisnikID11_, korisnik0_.agencija_AgencijaID as agencija8_11_, k' at line 1
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:318)
    at Servis.LoginServis.ProvjeraKorisnickihPodataka(LoginServis.java:35)
    at UI.LogInFrm.do_btnPrijava_widgetSelected(LogInFrm.java:173)
    at UI.LogInFrm$1.widgetSelected(LogInFrm.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at UI.LogInFrm.main(LogInFrm.java:44)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.KorisnikID as KorisnikID11_, korisnik0_.agencija_AgencijaID as agencija8_11_, k' at line 1
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1926)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1727)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:852)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2411)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2397)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2227)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2222)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:470)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:355)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1247)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:285)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.KorisnikID as KorisnikID11_, korisnik0_.agencija_AgencijaID as agencija8_11_, k' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4096)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4028)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2651)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2734)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2322)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 25 more
```

mapping goes like this:

```
/**
 ** Class Korisnik
 **/
    @Entity
public class Korisnik implements Serializable { 
  //Fields
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
  private Integer KorisnikID;
  private String ime;
  private String prezime;
  private String kontakt;
  private String korisnickoIme;
  private String lozinka;
  private Boolean isActive;
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
  private Agencija agencija;
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne
  private Rola rola;
```

and getters and setters go...

OK, my persistence.xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="MojaOznaka1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <!-- Podaci o bazi podataka -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxx/xxxxxxxxx/" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="xxxxxx" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="xxxxxx" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />


            <!-- hiberante dialect -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect" />
            <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
            <property name="connection.pool_size" value="1" />
            <!-- Ispis SQL koda u konzolu -->
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <!-- formatiranje SQL koda ispisanog u konzolni prozor -->
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
            <!-- Vrijednost "update" kreira tabele ako nepostoje -->
                    <!-- <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" /> -->
            <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
            <property name="current_session_context_class" value="thread" />
            <!-- Disable the second-level cache -->
            <property name="cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider" />
            <!-- automatsko prepoznavanje JPA klasa -->
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

OK, now what???

Comment: Can you add complete stack trace to the post also entities and their mapping?

Comment: I added it. if you need more let me know... thanks!

Comment: The point is the `TOP(?) korisnik0_.KorisnikID as KorisnikID11_` in your query. So.. what kind of database do you use? Can you show us your hibernate config?

Comment: <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

Comment: Oh, in stead of answering here, I will edit my post...

Comment: See my answer, your hibernate.dialect is wrong...

Comment: And database is: Database server

    Server: localhost via TCP/IP
    Software: MySQL
    Software version: 5.5.25a - MySQL Community Server (GPL)
    Protocol version: 10
    User: xxxxxxxxx
    Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Comment: SI or HCI my friend? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The query output you give suggests you told Hibernate to generate SQL for a MS-SQL Server (using `TOP(1)` to fetch the topmost row).

Since you're using a mysql database as a backend, that won't work. Try adding

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
```

to your persistence.xml or wherever you configure JPA.

As @Secko mentions in the comment, omitting the dialect altogether might even select a better (more specific) one.

Comment: This was so obvious that I could have spent eternity staring at it and would still missing it. I guess this is one of those beginner errors??? It works great. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: +1 Actually it's org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect and org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect for version 5 otherwise it causes more problems. JPA should interact with the sever itself and recognize the dialect and version if dialect property is ommited. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: @Secko Thanks for pointing that out. It's been a while since I last looked at the available dialects and it seems they grew quite a bit of subclasses. Probably no point in specifying `Mysql5InnoDBDialect` if Hibernate can auto-detect this.

Comment: @mabi True. One more thing, another problem occurs when you define a dialect and hibernate detects another. Everything compiles and executes fine, but then SQL queries fail for no reason. It's hard to detect this if you don't know what hibernate does.

Answer (score 1):

This error usually indicates some mapping error. Are all fields used in the where are actually fields of the "Korisnik" class? HQL uses the field names and not the column names from the database.

Comment: This is what Korisnik class has:

Comment: ...
  private Integer KorisnikID;
  private String ime;
  private String prezime;
  private String kontakt;
  private String korisnickoIme;
  private String lozinka;
  private Boolean isActive;
  ...

Comment: Does all column names match the field names? Try adding @Column(name = "...").

Comment: Can you give me example, I am not sure how to do it?

Comment: I got the same `SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000` message because I misspelled a column name.